# How to retrieve log4j2.xml if stored outside application

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am doing a maven application. If I place my `log4j2.xml` configuration file in the `src/resources` folder it works fine.

However, I need to store it outside the application. How can I call the location of the `log4j2.xml` file if it is stored, for example, on my desktop? Should I create a file in the `src/resource` folder that reads in my log file location and how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

The Log4j2 configuration file doesn't need to be in the classpath.

You can specify a relative or a full path with system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`.

See also the [Log4j2 FAQ page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location).

Comment: where do I put this code: Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml?

Comment: `-DpropertyName=propertyValue` is the command line syntax. E.g. `java -cp myjar.jar -Ddebug=true com.mycomp.MyMainClass`.